# Get sunday for specified date

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I get the date of the Sunday for a specified week?

Example, if I have a DateTime that contains a date of "11/19/2020", how can I get the Sunday for the week of 11/19? The value would be 11/13.

Comment: Why value should be `11/13/2020`? It is Friday o.O

Answer (score 2):

This is what you required

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(2020,11,19);           
int diff = d.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday;             
DateTime lastSunday = d.AddDays(-diff);           
Console.WriteLine(lastSunday);
```

Comment: This will work wherever Sunday is the first day of the week. That's not the case everywhere. In Europe (at least the largest part of it), Sunday is the last day of the week. In this case, you have to check the respective CultureInfo which is the first day of the week and have to use an offset.

Answer (score 0):

```
new DateTime(2020,11,19).AddDays(-(new DateTime(2020,11,19).DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday))
```